# Jquery accordion with table issues

Tags: javascript, css, html-table, jquery-ui-accordion

I am a beginner coder and need help with the following issues. I am trying to make a calendar using the jQuery accordion function with a table. Right now the full tables  are visible on the screen load. I want the accordion to be closed onload so you would only see the Month titles at first, then would open when a hover takes place. Also the calendar is shrinking when the accordion is triggered. I tried to par down the code to the basics. Any assistance would greatly be appreciated.

Here is the code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){


    $('table.CityTable th') .hover(
    function() {
        $(this) .parents('table.CityTable') .children('tbody') .toggle("slow");
    }
)

$('table.StateTable tr.statetablerow th') .hover(
    function() {
        $(this) .parents('table.StateTable') .children('tbody') .slideToggle("slow");
    }
)



});
    </script>


    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="container">
    <div id="contentarea"> <font class="title">2011  Calendar</font>
    <body>
    <div id="">
    <table class="StateTable" width="100%">
    <thead>
    <tr class="statetablerow">
    <th colspan="7">January</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
    <tr>
    <th valign=center align=middle bgcolor="#333333"><font color="#FFFFFF">Sunday</font></th>
    <th valign=center align=middle bgcolor="#333333"><font color="#FFFFFF">Monday</font></th>
    <th valign=center align=middle bgcolor="#333333"><font color="#FFFFFF">Tuesday</font></th>
    <th valign=center align=middle bgcolor="#333333"><font color="#FFFFFF">Wednesday</font></th>
    <th valign=center align=middle bgcolor="#333333"><font color="#FFFFFF">Thursday</font></th>
    <th valign=center align=middle bgcolor="#333333"><font color="#FFFFFF">Friday</font></th>
    <th valign=center align=middle bgcolor="#333333"><font color="#FFFFFF">Saturday</font></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td valign=top align=left></td>
    <td valign=top align=left></td>
    <td valign=top align=left></td>
    <td valign=top align=left></td>
    <td valign=top align=left</td>
    <td valign=top align=left></td>
    <td valign=top align=left>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td valign=top align=left>2</td>
    <td valign=top align=left>3</td>
    <td valign=top align=left>4</td>
    <td valign=top align=left>5</td>
    <td align=left valign=top>6</td>
    <td valign=top align=left>7</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td valign=top align=left>9</td>
    <td valign=top align=left>10</td>
    <td valign=top align=left>11</td>
    <td valign=top align=left>12</td>
    <td valign=top align=left>13</td>
    <td valign=top align=left>14</td>
    <td valign=top align=left>15</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td valign=top align=left>16</td>
    <td valign=top align=left>17</td>
    <td valign=top align=left>18</td>
    <td valign=top align=left>19</td>
    <td valign=top align=left>20</td>
    <td valign=top align=left>21</td>
    <td valign=top align=left>22</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td valign=top align=left>23</td>
    <td valign=top align=left>24</td>
    <td valign=top align=left>25</td>
    <td valign=top align=left>26</td>
    <td valign=top align=left>27</td>
    <td valign=top align=left>28</td>
    <td valign=top align=left>29</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td valign=top align=left></td>
    <td valign=top align=left></td>
    <td valign=top align=left></td>
    <td valign=top align=left></td>
    <td valign=top align=left></td>
    <td valign=top align=left></td>
    <td valign=top align=left></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>             
    </table>
    </div>


    <table class="StateTable" width="100%">
    <thead>
    <tr class="statetablerow">
    <th colspan="7">February</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>

    <tr>
    <th valign=center align=middle bgcolor="#333333"><font color="#FFFFFF">Sunday</font></th>
    <th valign=center align=middle bgcolor="#333333"><font color="#FFFFFF">Monday</font></th>
    <th valign=center align=middle bgcolor="#333333"><font color="#FFFFFF">Tuesday</font></th>
    <th valign=center align=middle bgcolor="#333333"><font color="#FFFFFF">Wednesday</font></th>
    <th valign=center align=middle bgcolor="#333333"><font color="#FFFFFF">Thursday</font></th>
    <th valign=center align=middle bgcolor="#333333"><font color="#FFFFFF">Friday</font></th>
    <th valign=center align=middle bgcolor="#333333"><font color="#FFFFFF">Saturday</font></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td valign=top align=left></td>
    <td valign=top align=left></td>
    <td valign=top align=left></td>
    <td valign=top align=left></td>
    <td valign=top align=left</td>
    <td valign=top align=left></td>
    <td valign=top align=left>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td valign=top align=left>2</td>
    <td valign=top align=left>3</td>
    <td valign=top align=left>4</td>
    <td valign=top align=left>5</td>
    <td align=left valign=top>6</td>
    <td valign=top align=left>7</td>
    <td valign=top align=left>8</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td valign=top align=left>9</td>
    <td valign=top align=left>10</td>
    <td valign=top align=left>11</td>
    <td valign=top align=left>12</td>
    <td valign=top align=left>13</td>
    <td valign=top align=left>14</td>
    <td valign=top align=left>15</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td valign=top align=left>16</td>
    <td valign=top align=left>17</td>
    <td valign=top align=left>18</td>
    <td valign=top align=left>19</td>
    <td valign=top align=left>20</td>
    <td valign=top align=left>21</td>
    <td valign=top align=left>22</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td valign=top align=left>23</td>
    <td valign=top align=left>24</td>
    <td valign=top align=left>25</td>
    <td valign=top align=left>26</td>
    <td valign=top align=left>27</td>
    <td valign=top align=left>28</td>
    <td valign=top align=left>29</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td valign=top align=left></td>
    <td valign=top align=left></td>
    <td valign=top align=left></td>
    <td valign=top align=left></td>
    <td valign=top align=left></td>
    <td valign=top align=left></td>
    <td valign=top align=left></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>             
    </table>

    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
    #container {width: 800px;height: 100%;top: 20px;bottom: 20px;text-align: center;margin: auto;left: auto;right: auto;}

    #contentarea {top: 240;height: 100%;width: 700px;right: 50px;left: 50px;padding-right: 40px;padding-left: 40px;}

    table.CityTable, table.StateTable{width="100%"}

    table.StateTable{margin:0px;}

    table td{padding:5px;}

    table.StateTable thead th{background: #333; padding: 5px; cursor:pointer; color:white;}

    table.CityTable thead th{cursor:pointer; color:black;}

    table.StateTable td.nopad{padding:0;}
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('table.StateTable tbody').hide(); //or add display:none in css
    $('table.StateTable').hover(
        function() {
            $(this).find('tbody').slideToggle("slow");
        },
        function() {
            $(this).find('tbody').slideToggle("slow");
        }) 
});
```

Comment: This is amazing. Thanks. Is there a way to get the Month background color to change if that month is the current one being displayed? Therefore showing that it is active.

Comment: you would probably be better off doing that with a server sidescript : in php `<?php if($month == 'your argument') {echo 'class="active"';} ?>` and then just style active in yourstyle sheet

Comment: Pleased to be able to help - if this answered your question please accept.

Comment: this is how you would do it with javascript : http://jsfiddle.net/Huw5Q/1/, my previous solution would be better.

Answer (score 0):

```css
 #container {width: 800px;height: 100%;top: 20px;bottom: 20px;text-align: center;margin: auto;left: auto;right: auto;}

    #contentarea {top: 240;height: 100%;width: 700px;right: 50px;left: 50px;padding-right: 40px;padding-left: 40px;}

    table.CityTable, table.StateTable{width="100%"}

    table.StateTable{margin:0px;}

    table td{padding:5px;}

    table.StateTable thead th{background: #333; padding: 5px; cursor:pointer; color:white;}

    table.CityTable thead th{cursor:pointer; color:black;}

    table.StateTable td.nopad{padding:0;}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div id="contentarea"> <font class="title">2011  Calendar</font>
    <div id="">
      <table class="StateTable" width="100%">
        <thead>
          <tr class="statetablerow header">
            <th colspan="7">January</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <th valign=center align=middle bgcolor="#333333"><font color="#FFFFFF">Sunday</font></th>
            <th valign=center align=middle bgcolor="#333333"><font color="#FFFFFF">Monday</font></th>
            <th valign=center align=middle bgcolor="#333333"><font color="#FFFFFF">Tuesday</font></th>
            <th valign=center align=middle bgcolor="#333333"><font color="#FFFFFF">Wednesday</font></th>
            <th valign=center align=middle bgcolor="#333333"><font color="#FFFFFF">Thursday</font></th>
            <th valign=center align=middle bgcolor="#333333"><font color="#FFFFFF">Friday</font></th>
            <th valign=center align=middle bgcolor="#333333"><font color="#FFFFFF">Saturday</font></th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td valign=top align=left></td>
            <td valign=top align=left></td>
            <td valign=top align=left></td>
            <td valign=top align=left></td>
            <td valign=top align=left</td>
            <td valign=top align=left></td>
            <td valign=top align=left>1</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td valign=top align=left>2</td>
            <td valign=top align=left>3</td>
            <td valign=top align=left>4</td>
            <td valign=top align=left>5</td>
            <td align=left valign=top>6</td>
            <td valign=top align=left>7</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td valign=top align=left>9</td>
            <td valign=top align=left>10</td>
            <td valign=top align=left>11</td>
            <td valign=top align=left>12</td>
            <td valign=top align=left>13</td>
            <td valign=top align=left>14</td>
            <td valign=top align=left>15</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td valign=top align=left>16</td>
            <td valign=top align=left>17</td>
            <td valign=top align=left>18</td>
            <td valign=top align=left>19</td>
            <td valign=top align=left>20</td>
            <td valign=top align=left>21</td>
            <td valign=top align=left>22</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td valign=top align=left>23</td>
            <td valign=top align=left>24</td>
            <td valign=top align=left>25</td>
            <td valign=top align=left>26</td>
            <td valign=top align=left>27</td>
            <td valign=top align=left>28</td>
            <td valign=top align=left>29</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td valign=top align=left></td>
            <td valign=top align=left></td>
            <td valign=top align=left></td>
            <td valign=top align=left></td>
            <td valign=top align=left></td>
            <td valign=top align=left></td>
            <td valign=top align=left></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>             
      </table>
    </div>


    <table class="StateTable t-month" width="100%">
      <thead>
        <tr class="statetablerow header">
          <th colspan="7">February</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th valign=center align=middle bgcolor="#333333"><font color="#FFFFFF">Sunday</font></th>
          <th valign=center align=middle bgcolor="#333333"><font color="#FFFFFF">Monday</font></th>
          <th valign=center align=middle bgcolor="#333333"><font color="#FFFFFF">Tuesday</font></th>
          <th valign=center align=middle bgcolor="#333333"><font color="#FFFFFF">Wednesday</font></th>
          <th valign=center align=middle bgcolor="#333333"><font color="#FFFFFF">Thursday</font></th>
          <th valign=center align=middle bgcolor="#333333"><font color="#FFFFFF">Friday</font></th>
          <th valign=center align=middle bgcolor="#333333"><font color="#FFFFFF">Saturday</font></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td valign=top align=left></td>
          <td valign=top align=left></td>
          <td valign=top align=left></td>
          <td valign=top align=left></td>
          <td valign=top align=left</td>
          <td valign=top align=left></td>
          <td valign=top align=left>1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td valign=top align=left>2</td>
          <td valign=top align=left>3</td>
          <td valign=top align=left>4</td>
          <td valign=top align=left>5</td>
          <td align=left valign=top>6</td>
          <td valign=top align=left>7</td>
          <td valign=top align=left>8</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td valign=top align=left>9</td>
          <td valign=top align=left>10</td>
          <td valign=top align=left>11</td>
          <td valign=top align=left>12</td>
          <td valign=top align=left>13</td>
          <td valign=top align=left>14</td>
          <td valign=top align=left>15</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td valign=top align=left>16</td>
          <td valign=top align=left>17</td>
          <td valign=top align=left>18</td>
          <td valign=top align=left>19</td>
          <td valign=top align=left>20</td>
          <td valign=top align=left>21</td>
          <td valign=top align=left>22</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td valign=top align=left>23</td>
          <td valign=top align=left>24</td>
          <td valign=top align=left>25</td>
          <td valign=top align=left>26</td>
          <td valign=top align=left>27</td>
          <td valign=top align=left>28</td>
          <td valign=top align=left>29</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td valign=top align=left></td>
          <td valign=top align=left></td>
          <td valign=top align=left></td>
          <td valign=top align=left></td>
          <td valign=top align=left></td>
          <td valign=top align=left></td>
          <td valign=top align=left></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>             
    </table>
</div>


<!--- Script -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-compat/3.0.0-alpha1/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
      
       $('table tbody').hide();
       $('table thead tr').mouseover(function() {
                $('table tbody').hide();
                $(this).parent().next().slideToggle("slow");
        });

      
    });
</script>
```